# Facing an issue with Terraform Init for GCP Provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am beginner and learning Terraform for GCP.

I just installed it in my windows system, and ran terraform init for my script. And, it only works once in 10 times, and I get this error most of the time (wsarecv: An existing
│ connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

I ran the below script as main.tf

```
provider "google" {
  project = "myprojectID"
  region  = "us-east1"
}
```

and, I get the following error most of the time, I have to try 10-15 times to get a success response

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...

- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/google from the dependency lock file
  ╷
  │ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
  │
  │ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/google: could not connect to
  │ registry.terraform.io: failed to request discovery document: Get
  │ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": read tcp
  │ [2601:182:d000:2d50:2471:f877:c128:eaff]:50468->[2600:9000:26dd:a800:16:1aa3:1440:93a1]:443: wsarecv: An existing
  │ connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Works fine for me ... from the error `could not connect to │ registry.terraform.io:` you will end up troubleshooting your network ... try running the init with trace: `export TF_LOG=TRACE; terraform init` that might give you some more debug information

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable IPV6 in your network settings. Please refer the link
https://anassblog.vercel.app/post/terraform-init-error/.

It worked for me!

Thanks to this conversation https://github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops/issues/592

Answer (score 0):

I found an unpleasant work-around.

I find that if I do an `nslookup` on the site Terraform is looking for and explicitly list it with an ipv4 IP address in my hosts (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) file, you get past this issue. For instance, my entry is:

3.161.188.103 registry.terraform.io

Unfortunately, you also need to list the IPs for all providers your Terraform configuration is using as well. This work-around is a pain.